# what is the difference between active directory and directory naming service

Tags: active-directory

what is the difference between active directory and directory naming service in Server 2003

Answer (score 0):

AD contains the users of your servers, computers in the network etc.

DNS is the URL your server will listen too, for example http://server01.lan.company.com